# Ball slows down in unity2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a blockbreaker type game coded using C# that mainly works fine but upon play testing i have found the ball will slow right down in certain situations! i.e if it wedges between to game object bricks the force of the ball rapidly slows down! 8 times out of ten this will not happen but other times it does and im unsure why! i will post the Ball script i think you will need to help solve this but should you need anymore information then please ask.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

private Paddle paddle;

private bool hasStarted = false;

private Vector3 paddleToBallVector;

void Start () {
    paddle = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Paddle> ();
    paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position - paddle.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!hasStarted) {
        //lock ball relative to the paddle
        this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;
        //wait for mouse press to start

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        //if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
        hasStarted = true;
            this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (2f, 10f);
        }
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){

    Vector2 tweak = new Vector2 (Random.Range(0f,0.2f),Random.Range(0f,0.2f));

    if (hasStarted) {
        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += tweak;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are adding directly to the velocity of the ball. The velocity variable defines a direction and speed, not just a speed as you are thinking here.

So, when the ball collides with a block it has a velocity of (+x, +y). After the collision and bounce is has a velocity of (+x, -y). So by adding a random positive value to the velocity when it has the -y velocity means that it will slow down the ball.

This does not happen every time because you are moving the ball in your Update() method. Change that to 'FixedUpdated()'. [Fixed Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) handles all physics calculations.

Also, I would recommend having a RigidBody2D on your Ball object. Moving physics objects should always have RigidBodies. With this, you can then use [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) in the forward direction of your ball and that should solve your problem.

EDIT: I see you have a RigidBody2D already. I missed that the first time. Instead of having `GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity` try `GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().AddForce( transform.forward * impulseAmount, ForceMode.Impluse );`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, line 28 on rigidbody whne using adforce comiples the error  "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer"
and line 40 for the GetCompont.rigidbody also gives error when using Addforce
"Cannot assign to `AddForce' because it is a `method group"

Comment: Oh yes, AddForce is a method. See my edit and I added a little more code. Hopefully that helps. Additionally, you will want to make sure your object's forward is always in the direction it is moving.

Comment: it doesnt seem to want to work for me, bringing up the doesnt exist in current contex error